# How do I check if a "name" value exists in a SQLLite Database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a SQLLite Database of sites with a name field. I have save and create buttons. I want to run my `addRecord()` or `updateRecord()` depending on whether or not the value in the name field exists.

I have this method in my `DBAdapter`:

```
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }
```

How can I create a similar method to get the `rowID` based on the name String supplied?

i.e.

```
public Cursor getRowID(String _name) {
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the name instead of the ID in your where clause.

```
public Cursor getRowID(String _name) {
    String where = "name = '" + _name + "'";
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Get the rowID from the cursor with something like this:

```
Cursor c = getRowID("John");
int rowID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID));
```